# Converting 'eregi_replace' function to 'preg_replace' and a 'mysql_num_rows' parameter fix

Tags: php, html, mysql, function, preg-replace

I've made a register.php file to sign up for a website I'm currently building. I'm running XAMPP to host my website and test it before I upload it via a paid host. After making the php file with the help of a few video's and online forums I opened it in google chrome and filled out the registration form I had created. But upon pressing 'submit' was presented with the following errors instead of having the user info successfully written into the mysql database.

> Deprecated: Function eregi_replace() is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\register.php on line 53
>
> Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\register.php on line 56
>
> Deprecated: Function eregi_replace() is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\register.php on line 97
>
> Deprecated: Function eregi_replace() is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\register.php on line 98
>
> Deprecated: Function eregi_replace() is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\register.php on line 99
>
> Deprecated: Function eregi_replace() is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\register.php on line 100

I know that the reason for errors related to the `eregi_replace()` function is because it is no longer being supported/used by the php language. I also am aware there is an alternative of `preg_replace()` However the problem stands that as a newbie in the field of php I am not able to come up with a solution. I'm learning a little more everyday but I need this page done quickly to continue on with my website and with school I don't have time to try out so many multiple blocks of code to come up with a solution. I apologize; I'm going to need a little spoon feeding. :/ If you can take my code and tell me how to fix the errors listed above, or even better respond with a fixed copy of the code, It would be very greatly appreciated! Thank you for your time and once again I apologize for my lack of knowledge.

register.php:

```
    <?php
//User check log
//include_once("Scripts/checkuserlog.php");
?>

<?php
// let's initialize vars to be printed to page in the HTML section so our script does not return errors 
// they must be initialized in some server environments
$errorMsg = "";
$firstname = "";
$lastname = "";
$email1 = "";
$email2 = "";
$pass1 = "";
$pass2 = "";

// This code runs only if the form submit button is pressed
if (isset ($_POST['firstname'])){
    
    /* Example of cleaning variables in a loop
    $vars = "";
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
       $value = stripslashes($value);
       $vars .= "$key = $value<br />";
    }
    print "$vars";
    exit();
    */
     $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
     $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
     $email1 = $_POST['email1'];
     $email2 = $_POST['email2'];
     $pass1 = $_POST['pass1'];
     $pass2 = $_POST['pass2'];

     $firstname = stripslashes($firstname);
     $lastname = stripslashes($lastname);
     $email1 = stripslashes($email1); 
     $pass1 = stripslashes($pass1); 
     $email2 = stripslashes($email2);
     $pass2 = stripslashes($pass2); 

     $firstname = strip_tags($firstname);
     $lastname = strip_tags($lastname);
     $email1 = strip_tags($email1);
     $pass1 = strip_tags($pass1);
     $email2 = strip_tags($email2);
     $pass2 = strip_tags($pass2);

     // Connect to database
     include_once "/Scripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
     $emailCHecker = mysql_real_escape_string($email1);
     $emailCHecker = eregi_replace("`", "", $emailCHecker);
     // Database duplicate e-mail check setup for use below in the error handling if else conditionals
     $sql_email_check = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM members WHERE email='$emailCHecker'");
     $email_check = mysql_num_rows($sql_email_check); 

     // Error handling for missing data
     if ((!$firstname) || (!$lastname) || (!$email1) || (!$email2) || (!$pass1) || (!$pass2)) { 

     $errorMsg = 'ERROR: You did not submit the following required information:<br /><br />';
  
     if(!$firstname){ 
       $errorMsg .= ' * First Name<br />';
     } 
     if(!$lastname){ 
       $errorMsg .= ' * Last Name<br />';
     } 
     if(!$email1){ 
       $errorMsg .= ' * Email Address<br />';      
     }
     if(!$email2){ 
       $errorMsg .= ' * Confirm Email Address<br />';        
     }  
     if(!$pass1){ 
       $errorMsg .= ' * Login Password<br />';      
     }
     if(!$pass2){ 
       $errorMsg .= ' * Confirm Login Password<br />';        
     }  
    
     } else if ($email1 != $email2) {
              $errorMsg = 'ERROR: Your Email fields below do not match<br />';
     } else if ($pass1 != $pass2) {
              $errorMsg = 'ERROR: Your Password fields below do not match<br />';
     } else if ($email_check > 0) { 
              $errorMsg = "<u>ERROR:</u><br />Your Email address is already in use inside our database. Please use another.<br />"; 
       
     } else { // Error handling is ended, process the data and add member to database
     ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    
     $firstname = mysql_real_escape_string($firstname);
     $lastname = mysql_real_escape_string($lastname);
     $email1 = mysql_real_escape_string($email1);
     $pass1 = mysql_real_escape_string($pass1);
     
     $firstname = eregi_replace("`", "", $firstname);
     $lastname = eregi_replace("`", "", $lastname);
     $email1 = eregi_replace("`", "", $email1);
     $pass1 = eregi_replace("`", "", $pass1);
     
     // Add MD5 Hash to the password variable
     $db_password = md5($pass1); 

     // Add user info into the database table for the main site table(audiopeeps.com)
     $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO members (firstname, lastname, email, password, sign_up_date) 
     VALUES('$firstname','$lastname','$email1','$db_password', now())")  
     or die (mysql_error());
 
     $id = mysql_insert_id();
     
     // Create directory(folder) to hold each user's files(pics, MP3s, etc.)        
     mkdir("members/$id", 0755);    

    //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!    Email User the activation link    !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    $to = "$email1";
                                         
    $from = "admin@Connect.CloudNine.com";
    $subject = "Complete your registration at Cloud Nine";
    //Begin HTML Email Message
    $message = "Hi $firstname,

   Complete this step to activate your login identity at [ yourdomain ].

   Click the line below to activate when ready.

   localhost/activation.php?id=$id&sequence=$db_password
   If the URL above is not an active link, please copy and paste it into your browser address bar

   Login after successful activation using your:  
   E-mail Address: $email1 
   Password: $pass1

   See you on the site!
   ";
   //end of message
    $headers  = "From: $from\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text\r\n";

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    
   $msgToUser = "<h2>One Last Step - Activate through Email</h2><h4>OK $firstname, one last step to verify your email identity:</h4><br />
   In a moment you will be sent an Activation link to your email address.<br /><br />
   <br />
   <strong><font color=\"#990000\">VERY IMPORTANT:</font></strong> 
   If you check your email with your host providers default email application, there may be issues with seeing the email contents.  If this happens to you and you cannot read the message to activate, download the file and open using a text editor.<br /><br />
   ";


   include_once 'msgToUser.php'; 

   exit();

   } // Close else after duplication checks

} else { // if the form is not posted with variables, place default empty variables
      
      $errorMsg = "Fields marked with an [ * ] are required";
      $firstname = "";
      $lastname = "";
      $email1 = "";
      $email2 = "";
      $pass1 = "";
      $pass2 = "";
}

?>

<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Welcome To Cloud Nine</title>
<link href="CSS/register.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="CSS/css_boxes_register.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="CSS/reg_table_register.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>

<body>
    <!--Floating Dock-->
    <div id="floating_dock">
    <a href="html_index.html" id="logo"><img src="Images/cloudnine_logo.png" width="220px"></a>
    <img src="Images/button.png" width="75" height="50" id="button"></div>
    <!--Floating Dock End-->
    
    <!--Content Wrap-->
<div id="container_alt">

<form action="register.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="box">
<h3>Account Registration</h3>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>

<table width="447" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1">
  <tr>
    <td width="435" align="center" valign="middle"><?php print "$errorMsg"; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">First Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center"><input name="firstname" type="text" id="firstname" value="<?php print "$firstname";?>" size="35" maxlength="35"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">Last Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center"><input name="lastname" type="text" id="lastname" value="<?php print "$lastname";?>" size="35" maxlength="35"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">Password</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center"><input name="pass1" type="text" id="pass1" value="<?php print "$pass1";?>" size="35" maxlength="35"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">Confirm Password</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center"><input name="pass2" type="text" id="pass2" value="<?php print "$pass2";?>" size="35" maxlength="35"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">Email</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center"><input name="email1" type="text" id="email1" value="<?php print "$email1";?>" size="35" maxlength="35"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">Confirm Email</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center"><input name="email2" type="text" id="email2" value="<?php print "$email2";?>" size="35" maxlength="35"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</p>
</form>

</div>
     


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.posix.php Your numrows problem is due to a query failing and a total lack of error handling - never EVER assume a database query has succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

No need to do regexp if you don't need it. Change

```
eregi_replace("`", "", $emailCHecker);
```

to

```
str_replace("`", "", $emailCHecker);
```

Do not use the mysql_* functions since they are deprecated. Use mysqli or PDO or whatever flavor you like but do not use mysql_* anymore!

> Use of this extension is discouraged. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL
>   extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and
>   related FAQ for more information.